# Cardview - why each element is painted only until the end of data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an android app, and I use in RecyclerView in one of the activities.

I created a CardView layout and RecyclerView layout and then Layout Manager and View adapter, and so on...

My question is, why it paints the background of each element, only "half", means only until the end of the word.

Look at this photo:
https://ibb.co/er9zGQ

My code is:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position)
{
    holder.nametxt.setText(tasksObj.get(position).getData());
    holder.nametxt.setTextSize(14);
    holder.nametxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffff99"));
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: because you set  width: wrap_content of textview, set it to match parent

Comment: simply, just set the width from wrap_content to match_parent. @ayelet  or set the backgroundcolor to your cardview.

Comment: show us your xml file also

Comment: please show your xml file

Comment: I tried to change to match parent, didn't fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with this

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position)
{
    holder.nametxt.setText(tasksObj.get(position).getData());
    holder.nametxt.setTextSize(14);
    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffff99"));
}
```

Comment: But a small question: now the corners of the cards are "sharp", and before it was more circle. It's not so important, but I preferred the older shape. How to do that>?

Answer (score 0):

because you have set wrap-content to your text view so it it will get width only as you have character's if you have to set background to all view then set background to your card view:

```
    holder.yourCardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffff99"));
```